# Django newbie question

Tags: python, django

I have this code :

```
def encode_myway(obj):
     if isinstance(obj, User):
        data = dict()
        data['username'] = obj.username
        data['code'] = obj.code //a number = 30
     return data
```

I'm serializing for json using `simplejson.dumps(resp, default=encode_myway)` the problem I have is that code (an integer) is equal to NULL but if I use `serializers.serialize("json", [resp,])` I got a lot of garbage in my json but the integers are correct.. for garbage I refer to something like this :

```
"[{\"pk\":\29,\\"model\":\\"smapp.userprofile\",\\"fields\":\{\"city\":\\"barcelona\", ... }}]"
```

Comment: Simplejson encodes objects based on the types that they are(not the type you think it should be), a None is mapped to null, so maybe double check that your "integer" is in fact an integer and is not None.

Comment: how I can check tha obj.code is a number?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be double-encoding. You don't show where `resp` comes from, but it seems to be JSON already.

Comment: resp comes from `resp = get_object_or_404(User,user=user.pk)`

Comment: You'are right .. I was double-encoding my json string.. using first `data = serializers.serialize("json", [resp,])` and then output `simplejson.dumps(data)` thank you, now I have a clean json string. anyway I'm still curious for the first part of my situation... why obj.code is getting null when I use `simplejson.dumps(resp, default=encode_myway)`